# What are some good photography podcasts?

Tags: learning

What are some good podcasts that deal with photography?

Please answer with **one podcast/link/description per answer** (so that members can then vote based on their opinions of that podcast).

Answer (score 6):

I really enjoy [PhotoFocus](http://photofocus.com/), by Scott Bourne.  He generally answers listener questions and talks with guests about photography and DSLR videography.

Comment: Note: Scott no longer does the podcast regularly. He is retiring from photography. Rich Harrington has taken over and does fewer listener questions with more interviews and gear lust.

Answer (score 4):

I really like [This Week in Photography](http://www.thisweekinphoto.com/), which is part of the TWiT nextwork.  Hosted by Frederick Van Johnson, the podcast covers all sorts of topics including gear, news, events, and techniques.

Answer (score 4):

[Tips from the top floor](http://www.tipsfromthetopfloor.com/) by Chris Marquardt

Answer (score 3):

I really enjoyed [Tack Sharp](http://5by5.tv/tacksharp), but they haven't put out any episodes since November 2009.

Answer (score 2):

Rick Sammon and Juan Pons' [Digital Photography Experience](http://dpexperience.com/) is a good combination of interviews with prominent photographers and Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

[HappyShooting](http://www.happyshooting.de/podcast) by Chris Marquardt and Boris Nienke, in german.

Answer (score 0):

Lenswork. The Lenswork podcast is the only one I'm still listening to years later, has done more to influence my photographic thinking than any other source, and discusses being an artist and creating art far more than using cameras and techno-details.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Nik Software's plugins for photo editing, then you'd probably benefit from [Nik Radio](http://www.niksoftware.com/teamnik/usa/entry.php?view=nik_radio/usa_main.shtml). I have picked up a few tips from that, but more importantly learned about some of their upcoming webinar offerings.

Answer (score -1):

I host and produce a podcast about photographers, called Photography 121.

How to listen?
There is quite a list of online resources to enable you to choose how you can access the podcast and listen online or download to your computer, mp3 player, phone, tablet, watch or other listening device. Here are two of them:

http://www.cotterell.net/_/Podcast/Podcast.html

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/podcast/photography-121/id425877463

Comment: Just a note: we try to avoid advertising, so whenever there may be some bias we like to acknowledge this connection (as you have done here)